# Использование std::invoke_result. Нужна шаблонная магия

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Продолжая знакомиться с содержимым заголовочного файла *type_traits* наткнулся на любопытное свойство типа `template<typename F, typename ... ArgTypes> class invoke_result;`

Был протестирован такой фрагмент кода:

```
template<typename F, typename... Argc>
using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Argc...>;
...
std::cout << typeid(type<int(char, double), char, double>).name();
```

Результат ожидаемый. На консоль выводится:

> int

Все хорошо, но дублирование **char, double** в  `type<int(char, double), char, double>` хотелось бы избежать. Например, хочу использовать в таком контексте:

```
template<typename F>
class FunctionPool {
    using ResultType = std::invoke_result_t<F, МАГИЯ И МЫ ПОЛУЧИЛИ ПАРАМЕТРЫ F>;  
    std::vector<std::pair<ResultType, F>> m_func;
};
```

Возможна ли такая магия? Или придется использовать `std::function<int(char, double)>::result_type`?

Comment: В таком контексте можно вообще ничего не писать, а сразу написать `int`

Comment: А что именно вы назвали "любопытным свойством"?

Comment: @AnT Видимо раз хедер - `<type_traits>`, то каждый отдельный шаблон в нем (вроде `invoke_result`) - "type trait", "свойство типа".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, проще всего написать свой небольшой trait:

```
template <typename T> struct return_type {};
template <typename T, typename ...P> struct return_type<T(P...     )         > {using type = T;};
template <typename T, typename ...P> struct return_type<T(P...     ) noexcept> {using type = T;};
template <typename T, typename ...P> struct return_type<T(P..., ...)         > {using type = T;};
template <typename T, typename ...P> struct return_type<T(P..., ...) noexcept> {using type = T;};
template <typename T> using return_type_t = typename return_type<T>::type;

std::cout << typeid(return_type_t<int(char, double)>).name();
```

Comment: В этом случае std::function<>::return_type делает не то же самое?

Comment: @PilgrimFromMars Я так понял, `std::function<>::return_type` не может обработать тип с `...` в списке параметров или с `noexcept`.